# how should I use Qt's UpdateGL() function without cleaning frame buffer?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I m working on a project like MS paint app. I use OpenGL and QtCreator and c++. I can draw rect,line or etc(2D shapes). I use mouse for drawing.(First click first x and y,Last click last x and y, additionally I use mouse's move event,too) When I try to draw more than one shapes all old shapes disappear.So how can keep my recent frame? I use  "glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);" func for cleaning buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store what you "paint" in a container, and each frame, draw your objects. You can store shapes, or strokes, etc.. and you can even do some history with that !

Comment: thanks for your answer .which method should I use to store frame in a container ?